Using External Access Integration in Snowflake to send csv-file to sftp-server takes forever
I experience a quite unusual high query time of 16mins with a Medium Warehouse while uploading a csv file of 3,4MB to a sftp server using the external access integration and the package paramiko. I based my approach on the following script:
https://gist.github.com/orellabac/46845bd1c378013b90124bb6bf9306f6
I've added some telemetry events and I saw, that it only takes 4.8s to create the dataframe and the csv file. It took then about 16mins to upload it, which makes me wondering why. It seems as if the connection is held open for an unusual long time.
I tested the hypothesis of a terribly slow sftp-server and have sent the same file to two different sftp-servers, getting the same result.
Besides that, I tried to upload the same csv-file via WinSCP by hand to the sftp-server and it took me just about 1s. Same thing when I try to execute the slightly modified code locally in VS Code.
A second hypothesis was, that pysftp might not be the best choice. That's why I have rewritten the code, so that my UDF uses the underlying framework paramiko. But even with that, I got 3s of querying + file creation and about 13 mins of uploading it.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upload_to_sftp_xxx(sftp_server STRING, sftp_port INT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'main'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (sftp_xxx)
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'paramiko', 're2', 'snowflake-telemetry-python')
SECRETS = ('cred' = sftp_creds_xxx)
AS
$$
import _snowflake
import paramiko
import re
import os
from snowflake import telemetry
from datetime import datetime
from snowflake.snowpark.files import SnowflakeFile

def main(session, sftp_server, sftp_port):
    creds = _snowflake.get_username_password('cred')
    telemetry.set_span_attribute("example.proc.do_tracing", "begin")
    telemetry.add_event("Credentials read", {"time": datetime.now()})

    df = session.sql('select * from XXX.XXX."XXX_filename"').toPandas()
    telemetry.add_event("Queried to pandas data frame", {"time": datetime.now()})
    csv_file_path = '/tmp/xxx_filename.csv'
    df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False, sep=';')
    telemetry.add_event("Written to csv", {"time": datetime.now()})

    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport((sftp_server, sftp_port))
        transport.connect(username=creds.username, password=creds.password)
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        telemetry.add_event("SFTP connection established", {"time": datetime.now()})

        sftp.put(csv_file_path, 'xxx_filename.csv')
        telemetry.add_event("Successfully uploaded to SFTP", {"time": datetime.now()})
        sftp.close()
        transport.close()
        telemetry.add_event("SFTP connection closed", {"time": datetime.now()})

        return "File uploaded successfully"
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        return f"Error with SFTP: {type(e).__name__}, {str(e)}, Traceback: {tb}"
$$;


I have absolutely no clue, why SF takes so long. Any idea for further testing or a very good answer why this happens is everything I'm hoping for.

Hi - I would raise this with Snowflake Support
